# Image hyperlinks in IE7 not clickable

Tags: hyperlink, internet-explorer-7

The images in the webpage below link to their respective pages. Works fine in IE8 & IE9 but not IE7.
In IE7 when you hover over the image the link url is recognised (previews in bottom left corner of browser) but is not clickable?

http://www.signport.co.uk/test/asg_ourwork.php

Can anyone tell me if there's a fix for it?

Thanks :)

Comment: This is what you have: <a><div shadow><p><img /></p></div></a>, can you try this: <a><span shadow></span><img /></a>

Comment: I changed it to this which worked, but I lost the shadow effect. I'm not sure if I've amended the code corrcetly?: <a href="asg_astonmartin.php">
         <span style="boxshadow"><p><img src="Images/thumb_aston2.jpg" alt="Aston Martin" height="170" width="300"></p></span></a>

Comment: Let me explain the error. You cannot have a div + p + img inside an "a" in IE7. You MUST have it like this I said and then correct the shadow. Can you please create a demo with my suggetion so I can help you with the shadow?

Comment: I've amended the Aston Martin image to your suggestion. The link now works. If I can get the shadows back that would be great. http://www.signport.co.uk/test/asg_ourwork.php

Comment: Please change the class name from "boxshadow" to boxshadow2 can you do it?

Comment: Should I change it on the css file or the asg_ourwork.php page?

Comment: Just the page so I can give you the final code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is the new solution:

### CSS

```
.item a{
   display:block;
   overflow:hidden;
   height:170px;
   -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px black;
   -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px black;
   -o-box-shadow:0 0 10px black;
   -ms-box-shadow:0 0 10px black;
   box-shadow:0 0 10px black;
}
```

You can DELETE the box-shadow SPAN you don't need it. I made it so you only need to add this line of code.

Comment: Correction for Homepage , try it, instead of **.item a** use **.item > a**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the hirarquy of the TAGS.

In **[this example](http://jsfiddle.net/ignaciocorreia/v64AD/2/)** you can see the correction working. In chrome it works exactly like yours. In IE7 the link works like you want, you only need to correct the rollover.

### The Problem:

```
 <div style="opacity: 1;" class="item">
    <a href="http://www.signport.co.uk/test/asg_ask.php">
    <div class="boxshadow">
        <p>
            <img src="http://www.signport.co.uk/test/Images/thumb_ask.jpg" alt="ASK Italian" height="170" width="300">
        </p>
        </div>
      </a>
</div>
```

### The Solution

**HTML**

```
    <div style="opacity: 1;" class="item">
    <a href="http://www.signport.co.uk/test/asg_ask.php">
        <span class="boxshadow"></span>
       <img src="http://www.signport.co.uk/test/Images/thumb_ask.jpg" alt="ASK Italian" height="170" width="300">
     </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.projects .item{box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 black;padding:0;margin:10px;}
.projects a {display: block;height: 150px;margin-bottom: 20px;}
.projects a .boxshadow {position: absolute;z-index: 999999;box-shadow: none;}
```